# How return an object of a struct from c to Mathematica?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

I'm writing a c code by using WSTP library. In my c codes, I have a struct named Person, and I have a function named Foo, which returns an object of Person.

```
struct Person
{
   int id;
   char* name;
};

Person* Foo()
{
   Person* person = new Perosn();
   ...
   return person; 
}
```

My problem is in the [.tm](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/file.tm.html) file, I don't know how can I determine the return type. Please guide me.

Comment: You have used the Manual return type in your last question, so I assume you are familiar with it. This is what you need to do here. BTW you never responded to the comments on your last question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [file.tm](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/file.tm.html), you need to set the return type to `Manual`, and declare your C(++) function to be `void`.

Then return each piece of data making up the struct separately, using low-level MathLink functions.

In this case, you could return a [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) of an integer and a string, i.e. use

```
WSPutFunction(stdlink, "List", 2);
  WSPutInteger(stdlink, person->id);
  WSPutString(stdlink, person->name);
```

at the end of the function.

Comment: This is a promising answer, though may need some more background info or a link to the relevant doc. What is `stdlink`? Is it an instance of `WSLINK`?

Comment: @AntiEarth http://www.edenwaith.com/development/tutorials/mathlink/ML_Tut.pdf http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/174/ or search for WSTP in the docs.

Comment: @AntiEarth http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WSTPAndExternalProgramCommunicationOverview.html WSTP and MathLink are the same, but incompatible (= non-mixable) due to different naming (ML vs WS). There's no functional difference.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much!

Comment: do you know of any support for returning Associations?

Comment: @AntiEarth Currently MathLink has no (documented) support for atomic associations. This means that you need to put the compound expression on the link: head `Association`, followed by several `Rule`s. This is true for several atomic types, e.g. sparse arrays.

Comment: @AntiEarth The WXF format does support associations directly, and might be used for this purpose. You can transfer the WXF data through MathLink or LibraryLink. I have not done this yet. It is a recently introduced format. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WXFFormatDescription.html

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks! Using `WSPutFunctioN(stdlink, "Association", etc...)` works great to send an Association **to** MMA, but how can I receive and extract the rules (which are fixed and known apriori) from an Association passed to C?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87047/discussion-between-szabolcs-and-anti-earth).